# crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++

char* SequenceTokenAnalizer::NextToken(char delim)
{

```
int main()
{
SequenceTokenAnalizer st1("This is a test");
    char* helpSequence;
    helpSequence = st1.NextToken();
    cout << helpSequence << endl;
    delete[]  helpSequence;
}

int i = currentindex, i2 = currentindex, cnt = 0, j = 0;
char *token=NULL;

if (Sequence[i2] == delim)
{
    while (Sequence[i2] == delim&& Sequence[i2] != '\0')
    {
        i2++;

    }
    while (Sequence[i2] != delim&& Sequence[i2]!='\0')
    {
        cnt++;
        i2++;
    }
    token = new char[cnt];
    if (Sequence[i] == delim)
    {
        while (Sequence[i] == delim)
        {
            i++;

        }
        while (Sequence[i] != delim&& Sequence[i2] != '\0')
        {
            token[j] = Sequence[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        token[j] = '\0';
        currentindex = i;
        return token;
    }
}
    else
    {
        while (Sequence[i2] != delim)
        {
            cnt++;
            i2++;
        }
        token = new char[cnt];


        if (Sequence[i] == delim)
        {
            while (Sequence[i] == delim)
            {
                i++;

            }
            while (Sequence[i] != delim)
            {
                token[j] = Sequence[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
            currentindex = i;
            return token;
        }
        else
        {
            while (Sequence[i] != delim)
            {
                token[j] = Sequence[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            token[j] = '\0';
            currentindex = i;
            return token;
        }
    }
```

class:

#include

#include

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 80;

class SequenceTokenAnalizer {

```
char Sequence[SIZE];
char delimiter;
int currentindex;
```

public:

```
SequenceTokenAnalizer(char str[]);

SequenceTokenAnalizer(char str[], char delim);

int LengthSequence();

int CountAllTokens();
void ResetTokens();
int CountTokens();
bool HasMoreTokens();
bool HasMoreTokens(char delim);
char* NextToken();
char* NextToken(char delim);
bool Equals(SequenceTokenAnalizer other);
bool NotEquals(SequenceTokenAnalizer other);
bool isCommonToken(SequenceTokenAnalizer other);
void PrintCommonTokens(SequenceTokenAnalizer other);
```

};

after using delete[] in main I get crt detected that the application  wrote to memory after end of heap buffer please helppppp here i have sequences and have to return next tokken from current index
after using delete[] in main I get crt detected that the application  wrote to memory after end of heap buffer please helppppp here i have sequences and have to return next tokken from current index

Comment: What are you trying to delete? I can't see a delete anywhere in here.

Comment: int main()
{

char* helpSequence;
  helpSequence = st1.NextToken();
  cout << helpSequence << endl;
  delete[]  helpSequence;
}

Comment: Please edit your post and add it in to your question.

Comment: Why are you using char*? std::string might be better for you unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise.

Comment: i have sentences and make tokens so i have to return the next token from corrent index our teacher want us to use token as char*

Comment: Please edit your post and insert all the code in `code` marks. You can use the CTRL+K shortcut.

Comment: it doesnt let me do that can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the constructor, but I asume `"This is a test"` is the input and `' '` is the delimiter and currentindex=0.

Now follow the code

```
if (Sequence[i2] == delim)
```

This is false, because `i2=0` and `Sequence[0]` contains `'T'`. So skip to the else part.

```
    while (Sequence[i2] != delim)
    {
        cnt++;
        i2++;
    }
    token = new char[cnt];
```

`i2` must be increased 4 times to reach the space. That means cnt will also be 4 and you allocate 4 bytes.

```
    if (Sequence[i] == delim)
```

Because `i` starts at the save value as `i2` this is always false. So again move to the else part

```
        while (Sequence[i] != delim)
        {
            token[j] = Sequence[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        token[j] = '\0';
```

Now you are copying `"This"` into the 4-byte buffer, but also write `'\0'` at the 5th position.

---

Before your edit your code contained this part which was also wrong:

```
token2 = new char[strlen(token)];
strcpy(token2, token);
```

strlen returns the length without the `'\0'`, but strcpy uses it.

Also, this looks like a copy/paste mistake:

```
while (Sequence[i] != delim&& Sequence[i2] != '\0')
```

I would expect `i` instead of `i2`

Comment: i updatet the code it works without delete[] in main but when i put delete i get the error above

Comment: It does not make it easier for us if you modify the code after posting. But anyway you are only posting a part, if you really want us to help post complete code which is possible for us to compile.

Comment: and add the input you are using.

Comment: it doesnot give me to edit and add can i upload the whole file as zip ?

Comment: what i can do i have the all project but when i edit it give me that it doesnt formated as code